# How to register different objects with same interface

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm using c# and the unity IOC container.

I have come up with a situation where I need to register multiple objects with the same interface. In this situation how do I register/resolve these required objects from unity?

For example I need 2 different versions of the logger in the same viewmodel

```
Class DatabaseLogger : Ilogger {...}
Class FileLogger : Ilogger {...}
```

How can I register and resolve these both in my viewmodel?

I could do the following :

```
Class DatabaseLogger : IDatabaseLogger {...}
Class FileLogger : IFileLogger {...}
```

Is this the best way?

Answer (score 0):

log4net or the Enterprise Library Logging Application Block have their own means to write output to multiple targets (file, eventlog, database, console, ...).

I would expect this functionality from any other mature logging library out there as well. Its just a matter of the configuration of these frameworks where your messages end up.

Thus you would not need to create your own logger classes. And creating interfaces with just a single implementation (`IFileLogger`, `IDatabaseLogger`, `IEventLogLogger`, `IConsoleLogger`, ...) makes the interface pretty [useless as a means of abstraction](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/02/InterfacesAreNotAbstractions.aspx).

If you don't use such a library you might consider switching to a proven solution instead.